# Override Java constructor in Scala

Tags: android, scala, opengl-es-2.0

[In the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html#glsurfaceview), it says I should make the new class like this:

```
class MyView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setRenderer(renderer);
    }
}
```

Now I tried to re-do that in Scala:

```
class BaseGameActivity extends Activity {
    object glview extends GLSurfaceView(this) {
        setRenderer(renderer)
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2)
    }
}
```

However, the App crashes now with the exception "`java.lang.IllegalStateException: setRenderer already called for this instance`". I suspect this has to do with the way Scala calls the super-constructor.

I've tried to find out how to override the constructor in the way [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html#glsurfaceview) describe, but couldn't find it. I'd appreciate any hint.

Comment: There's no such thing as overriding constructors. The only kind of polymorphism that constructors support is overloading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your are propagating the call to a different constructor from the base class. You are passing a reference to `this` instead of a reference to the `Context` object. It might be that this other constructor is calling `setRenderer`.

Could you try to create an inner class `MyGLView` like this:

```
class MyGLView(ctx: Context) extends GLSurfaceView(ctx) {
  setRenderer(renderer)
}
```

And see what happens?

The problem is that `object` does not allow arguments to its constructor. Top-level objects must be initializable without any arguments (nobody calls their ctors). In your case you have an inner object, which can reference the members of the surrounding class instance. If you really need an inner object in your `Activity` class, you could do:

```
object glview extends GLSurfaceView(ctx) {
  setRenderer(renderer)
}
```

where `ctx` is a member of the surrounding class.

Comment: So I can't use `object` here at all?

Comment: You can, if you can provide a `ctx` argument when you extend a `GLSurfaceView`.

Comment: Could it be that Scala calls the super-Constructor *after* the own initialisations?

Comment: This is highly unlikely, but you could check the bytecode using `javap`, and verify that.

Answer (score 0):

In java likewise in scala constructors [are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance).

So you can not override thing, you didnt inherit. And you should use one of existing constructors for base class. If all of them are calling `setRenderer(renderer)` it will be called during constructing super object and you obviously should not call it second time in a subtype constructor ( wheither it class, object or mixing-in trait ).