# Differentiate between BigDecimal for money and BigDecimal for percentages

Tags: java, inheritance, bigdecimal

I use `BigDecimal` throughout my application to handle **money** and **percentages**. But, I need a way to differentiate usage between the two (for the purpose of rendering them, i.e., in a `JTable`). So, my initial thought was to write two classes which behave exactly like `BigDecimal` so that I could do `instanceof` tests on them. So I wrote this code:

**DollarValue.java:**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class DollarValue extends BigDecimal {

}
```

**PercentValue.java:**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class PercentValue extends BigDecimal {

}
```

However, in order to use the constructors ([because they cannot be inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1644410/963076)), I you need to manually override every constructor. So, DollarValue.java became a monstrosity:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.math.MathContext;

public class DollarValue extends BigDecimal {

    public DollarValue(char[] in, int offset, int len) {
        super(in, offset, len);
    }
    public DollarValue(char[] in, int offset, int len, MathContext mc) {
        super(in, offset, len, mc);
    }
    public DollarValue(char[] in) {
        super(in);
    }
    public DollarValue(char[] in, MathContext mc) {
        super(in, mc);
    }
    public DollarValue(String val) {
        super(val);
    }
    public DollarValue(String val, MathContext mc) {
        super(val, mc);
    }
    public DollarValue(double val) {
        super(val);
    }
    public DollarValue(double val, MathContext mc) {
        super(val, mc);
    }
    public DollarValue(BigInteger val) {
        super(val);
    }
    public DollarValue(BigInteger val, MathContext mc) {
        super(val, mc);
    }
    public DollarValue(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale) {
        super(unscaledVal, scale);
    }
    public DollarValue(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale, MathContext mc) {
        super(unscaledVal, scale, mc);
    }
    public DollarValue(int val) {
        super(val);
    }
    public DollarValue(int val, MathContext mc) {
        super(val, mc);
    }
    public DollarValue(long val) {
        super(val);
    }
    public DollarValue(long val, MathContext mc) {
        super(val, mc);
    }
}
```

But what's worse, in implementation, this didn't work because I use the static `BigDecimal` code a lot. To illustrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DollarValue dollars = DollarValue.ONE;
    DollarValue dollars2 = DollarValue.valueOf(25);
}
```

throws an error, because `DollarValue.ONE` is actually a `BigDecimal`, not a `DollarValue` and `DollarValue#valueOf()` returns a `BigDecimal` too.

So now I'm out of ideas. What is the easiest way to distinguish between two implementations of the same class in the way I'm trying to achieve?? This seems like a simple problem...

Edit: Any solution that allows me to automatically differentiate between the two in a renderer will also work. For instance, I need to feed the values to a `JTable` and have the `JTable` display either a dollar sign `$` for money or a percent sign `%` for percentages.

Comment: A percentage is just one number divided by another, multiplied by 100.  You need special classes for that?

Comment: I strongly recommend using the [Joda-Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) library for working with money, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel yourself.  Working with money is a common, and tricky, problem.  Let other people solve it for you.

Comment: Prefer encapsulation over inheritance here

Comment: Typically IDEs such as Eclipse can auto-generate a lot of that code for you.

Comment: @arshajii, I left that out. Generating that code in Netbeans was extremely cumbersome...

Comment: @RobertHarvey, it is mostly for a `JTable` renderer, so that I can set the default renderer for `PercentValue` to display differently than for `DollarValue`.

Comment: @hexafraction, for the same reason I just mentioned to @RobertHarvey, I need to feed the values to a `JTable` renderer which needs to differentiate between percentages and dollar amounts for display purposes. So, is there an easy way to achieve that with encapsulation?

Comment: Yes, by having two different classes you're using. One for percentages, the other for money.

Comment: Just checking if you know that `table.getColumnModel().setCellRenderer(...)` can set explicit renderers for individual columns(?)

Comment: Define 'differentiate'. You don't need different classes to accomplish that.

Comment: @LukeUsherwood, I was hoping for something more along the lines of `table.setDefaultRenderer(DollarValue.class, new DollarValueRenderer())` (and, a different one for percentages). Also, not just for tables but even to know which `DecimalFormat` to apply to the decimal if it is put into a `JLabel` or `JTextField`, etc.

Comment: I'm going to follow @dimo414's advice and use Joda-Money. I was hesitant to take time and learn _yet-another_ non-standard API but c'est la vie.

Comment: You only need to provide the constructors that you actually need to calll. Do you really need all those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using the [Joda-Money](http://www.joda.org/joda-money/) library for working with money, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel yourself. Working with money is a common, and tricky, problem. Let other people solve it for you.

It's always a little frustrating to add a new dependency to your project, but when it comes to core utility libraries that provide obvious, but tricky to implement, benefits, it should be a no-brainer.  Some other critical libraries are:

- [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) - this should absolutely be part of any modern Java codebase.  The utilities and new collections provided are irreplaceable valuable.
- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (unless you're on [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)) - like money, time is a deeply tricky data structure to properly represent (as Java's long-broken [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and associated classes prove) and Joda-Time provides a robust and well thought out interface.

There are many other libraries that I could call out as worth using, but you're truly making a mistake if you aren't using these three.  While technically "non-standard", like you note, these are so ubiquitous that they aren't far from being conceptually expected parts of a Java developer's toolbelt.

Answer (score 1):

Use composition, rather than inheritance. Do all the arithmetic in BigDecimal, but have two classes that each has a constructor that takes a BigDecimal argument and a getValue method that returns the BigDecimal.

Code would look a bit more complicated:

```
DollarValue dollars = new DollarValue(BigDecimal.ONE);
DollarValue dollars2 = new DollarValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(25));
DollarValue sum = new DollarValue(dollars.getValue().add(dollars2.getValue()));
```

If there are a few really common operations for one of the classes, implement the directly in that class. For example, DollarValue could have:

```
public DollarValue sum(DollarValue other) {
  return new DollarValue(getValue().add(other.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: More of it, do not use inheritance when the subclass doesn't behave exactly like the inherited class (which is LSP rule violation) - this is very bad practice.