# Why do I need another constructor in an extended abstract class?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class, default-constructor

I've come across this issue and I'm wondering what is the difference here:

```
abstract class Abstract {
    Abstract() {
        System.out.println("Abstract.Abstract()");
    }

    Abstract(String s) {
        System.out.println("Abstract.Abstract(String)");
    }

    void test() {
        System.out.println("Abstract.test()");
    }

    void test(String s) {
        System.out.println("Abstract.test(s)");
    }
}

abstract class Base extends Abstract {
}

class Sub extends Base {
    Sub(String s) {
        super(s);   // undefined constructor
    }

    void subTest(String s) {
        super.test(s);  // why is this all right then?
    }
}
```

Why do I have to define `Base(String s)` constructor to make it compilable but the `super.test(s)` call is fine without defining anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java provides you with default constructors in *any* class (even if you don't define one yourself), meaning you have `Base()` default constructor in class `Base`, but not any other constructor (one that takes arguments, such as `Base(String s)`) [because constructors are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance) .

In addition, extending a class gives you its methods via inheritance, so calling `super.test(s)` is legal here because `Base` has the method `test(String s)` inherited from `Abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Base` only defines a single constructor, the no-args default one which calls the superclass no-args constructor.

Now, which superclass cunstructors are available to `Sub`? Just one.