# how to avoid repetitive constructor in children

Tags: java, dry

I have a parent class, which has constructor as:

```
    @Inject
    public AbstractResource(@Named("authorization") Authorization auth,
                            @Named("helper") Helper helper) {
        this.authorization = authorization;
        this.helper = helper;
    }
```

now in the children class, i have similar constructor:

```
public class MyResource extends AbstractResource {
        private Manager manager;

        @Inject
        public MyResource(@Named("authorization") Authorization auth,
                          @Named("helper") Helper helper) {
            super(auth, helper);
            this.manager = new Manager();
        }
...
```

Problem is I have tons of children class extend from AbstractResource, I have to write the similar constructor with 'Authorization' and 'Helper' again and agin. is there any way i can avoid the repetitive coding?

Sorry, updated my code, yes, i can call super(..) in each children class, but still in each constructor i have inject all those parameters, auth and helper, just wonder if there is a way to even simplify that

Comment: With constructor injection, no. But you could use setter or field injection if you find it fine.

Comment: almost dupe but I think you're interested in the Guice or Spring case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something about this there is a simple solution by calling through to the parent's constructor.

In your child class's constructor the first line should be: `super(authorization, helper)`

EDIT: Author has edited his question so this solution is no longer applicable.

Comment: This is what I thought too, but I'm not too familiar with the @Named Annotation.

Comment: This looks right. You can get rid of 1/2 the boilerplate, not the other half.

Comment: If your answer is no longer applicable, I suggest you delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object to hold all the arguments.

But other than that, no not really. This is what production DI code in Java actually looks like.