# How to avoid changing every child constructor when parent constructor changes

Tags: c++, inheritance, design-patterns, constructor

Say I have the following (C++)

```
class Parent
{
     Parent(Foo f){};
}

class Child : public Parent
{
    Child(Foo f, Bar b)
        : Parent(f)
    {};
}
...
// And a whole bunch of other children, all calling Parent constructor
```

Suppose now I need to add a new parameter to the Parent constructor

```
Parent(Foo f, Baz z){};
```

Then I will have to change every single child class to the following

```
Child(Foo f, Baz z, Bar b)
    : Parent(f, z)
{};
```

Is there anyway I can avoid having to change every single child class?

Guess might be related to this,
[how to avoid repetitive constructor in children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372707/how-to-avoid-repetitive-constructor-in-children)
which suggests that I must change every child class.

If so, are there any languages / design patterns that would make such a change less painful?

Comment: Do the child classes use the new parameter in any way? If not then let the parent have two constructors.

Comment: If you have so many subclasses that this is actually a chore, there's a fair chance that you should reconsider your design instead.

Answer (score 2):

If the new argument to the parent constructor is *mandatory* then there really no choice, you have to update the child classes constructors.

But if the new argument is *not* mandatory, just add the new parent constructor as an overloaded constructor, or use a default value for the new argument.