# How to override color and font for a JLabel?

Tags: java, jlabel

I need to create a class `XLabel` that would have customized color and font.

I need all `JLabels` to have the following  effect

```
 JLabelTest.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 20)); 
 JLabelTest.setForeground(Color.PINK);
```

This is what I tried

```
public class XLabel extends JLabel {

    @Override 
    public void setFont(Font f)
       {
        super.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 20));
         repaint();
        }

    @Override 
    public void setForeground(Color fg)
       {  
        super.setForeground(Color.PINK); 
         repaint();
       }     
}
```

However, when I try to use it   `XLabel test= new XLabel("test")`  does not compile , because constructor `XLabel (String )` is undefined. But it extends `JLabel` , so it should inherit all it's constructors . Why doesn't it  ? How to set  customized color and font ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Constructor Inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to override those methods. `JLabel` is an abstract class, so `XLabel` automatically inherits those methods. Remove those methods from the `XLabel` class and try specifying the foreground and font in the constructor.

```
public class XLabel extends JLabel {

public XLabel(String text) {
    super(text);
    this.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    this.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 20));
}
```

Then, whenever you create an instance of `XLabel`, the methods `setForeground()` and `setFont()` are automatically called. This makes any instance of XLabel have the color pink, and the font Comic Sans.

Comment: This is exactly what I do. But this results in duplicate code. when I have hundreds of those `JLabel` elements and `setFont` and `setForeground` for each.

Comment: Ahh. You didn't specify that you'd need multiple JLabels with these exact properties in the question. You'd simply create a constructor for `XLabel` which sets the font and foreground. I'll update my answer with the correct code.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I also tried that. This constructor is only good for when we instantiate without any arguments. It won't work when I use `XLabel test = new XLabel("test")`  because constructor `XLabel (String ) is undefined`

Comment: Thank you . i was messing for hours with the `paintComponent` and other methods

Comment: No problem! Also, the better way to do it is to use `super(text)` now that I think about it. Edited it again. But either way works.