# Java: How constructors and methods behave with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

Java seems to be inconsistent in how class constructors and methods deal with inheritance.

**Case 1 - Methods:**

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Bee b = new Bee();
    b.foo();
  }
}

class Insect {
  public void foo() {
    this.bar();
    System.out.println("Insect foo");
  }

  public void bar() {
    System.out.println("Insect bar");
  }
}

class Bee extends Insect {
  @Override
  public void foo() {
    super.foo();
    System.out.println("Bee foo");
  }

  @Override
  public void bar() {
    System.out.println("Bee bar");
  }
}
```

The above code outputs the following:

> Bee bar
>
> Insect foo
>
> Bee foo

Notice the call to "this.bar()" in Insect's foo() method actually goes back and calls Bee's bar() method (instead of calling Insect's bar() method).

**Case 2 - Constructors:**

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Bee i = new Bee(1);
  }
}

class Insect {
  public Insect(int size) {
    this(size, 123);
    System.out.println("Constructor: Insect size");
  }

  public Insect(int size, int height) {
    System.out.println("Constructor: Insect size, height");
  }
}

class Bee extends Insect {
  public Bee(int size) {
    super(size);
    System.out.println("Constructor: Bee size");
  }

  public Bee(int size, int height) {
    super(size, height);
    System.out.println("Constructor: Bee size, height");
  }
}
```

The above outputs the following.

> Constructor: Insect size, height
>
> Constructor: Insect size
>
> Constructor: Bee size

Notice the call to "this(size, 123);" in Insect's constructor goes to Insect's 2nd constructor instead of bee's 2nd constructor.

So in summary, *method* calls go back to the subclass while *constructor* calls stay in the superclass.  Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Because methods can be overridden while constructors can't.

Comment: [JLS 8.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8): "Constructor declarations are not members. They are never inherited and therefore are not subject to hiding or overriding"

Comment: Have you read about virtual methods or virtual calls)?

Comment: shouldn't case 2 be a compilation error? because of the @Override on the constructor of the Bee class

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: KevinO basically got it.  Constructors do not participate in inheritance.  It may be a bit surprising but that is the way the language is specified.

Comment: Overriding a constructor cannot be done, I can see you have used @Override on constructor.

Comment: This is basic textbook stuff that you just have to learn and accept as gospel.  Your life as a Java programmer will be much easier once you do.

Comment: Woops, added those @Overrides right before I posted.  Anyway the answers make sense to me, thanks guys.

Comment: You may find reading this fruitful, if you are wondering the reasons why:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance

Comment: Questions like this can be answered independently if one looks up the answers in the Java documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the correct information in the comments about *methods* being not the same as *constructors* - you are actually *over-simplifying* things.

You see, when you write constructors, you **have** to **decide** if you intend to use a "same class" constructor (when you use `this()`) - or if you want to invoke a super class constructor (using `super()`) instead. There is no middle ground here - you have to be explicit about this!

Keep in mind: the responsibility of a constructor is to **initialize** an object of the corresponding class. It can make a **huge** difference if you call `this(whatever)` or `super(whatever)` within your constructors.

The compiler can't know what you intend to do. Therefore you **have** to be explicit about the exact *other* constructor you want to be invoked.

And beyond that - it simply doesn't make sense to have *polymorphism* kick in here like this. You absolutely want that **object initialization** takes place as you *expect* it to happen. Because *wrongly* initialized objects for sure create problems *later on*.

Your idea of making constructors polymorphic basically means that you determine at *runtime* which constructor to invoke. But you already **know** that you are in class X, and that you have to initialize a new X object. There is nothing to gain from allowing polymorphism here. To the contrary - doing so would allow for very strange and bizarre problems that would be purely runtime only!