# If constructor is not inherited in java then why it parent class constructor is called in subclass by default?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

Lets say we have two classes:

```
public class A{
  public A(){
    System.out.println("A");
  }
}
```

and its subclasas

```
public class B extends A{
   public B(){
      System.out.println("B");
   }
}
```

The output below would be 
A
A
B

```
public static main(String[] args){
 A a = new A();
 B b = new B();
 }
```

WHY like this is constructor is not inherited?
SHould not we call super() in subclass constructor to call constructor of parent?

thanks

Comment: no. that is automatically arranged by the vm. when you look at compiled code, the call will be there.

Comment: Why do you think "constructor inheritance" is related to "calling super constructor when building a subclass"?

Comment: You are not inheriting a constructor, when you create an instance of B it will first call the appropriate constructor to create A.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is...but the results you show are as I would expect from the code posted.

Comment: @Stultuske Please be precise about wording. The **VM** has nothing to do  with this - it is the compiler inserting the corresponding byt3e code instructions.

Comment: The main thing to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1644363/1531124

Comment: @GhostCat the compiler puts it there, the vm detects it on runtime. where-as my comment was far from complete, and could/should be worded better, on runtime, it is not handled by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

when you create object of child class then super() call automatic by jvm for non-parameterized constructor.

and if your constructor is parameterized then you have to call by passing parameters like super(parameters).