# Valid object declarations and using dot operators

Tags: java, object

```
public class Top{ 
    public int top = 1;
    public Top(int top){ this.top = top; }
}
```

```
public class Middle extends Top{
    public Middle(int top){
        super(top);
        this.top = this.top + top;
    }
}
```

```
public class Bottom extends Middle{
    public Bottom(){ super(3); }
    public Bottom(int top){
        super(top);
        this.top = top;
    }
}
```

For this class, I'm confused as to why Top t = new Top() is a invalid declaration? Does it have to have a passing argument for this object t being created to be valid?

Why is 1) Top t = new Bottom() and 2) Top t = new Top(3) valid? I'm new to java and Does the bottom class have an empty constructor so 1) is valid?

Also, say for example Top t = new Middle(2), how would I proceed to figure out what t.top without using code? Like the dot operator always throws me off, what I'm thinking is that the object "t" is being associated with the attributes of the top variable? It's supposed to equal 4 but I'm trying to figure this out but these concepts seem so foreign to me right now. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the code you're asking about **in the question itself**, as text. Not as a link to an image. We can't copy and paste from an image. Blind people can't read an image.

Comment: Polymorphism. And because `Top` is not abstract.

Comment: Why should `Top` know that a subclass provides a default constructor?

Comment: Also there exists no such thing as [constructor-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance) in the first place

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused as to why Top t = new Top()

Because `Top` has no no-args constructor. If you add one like you did in `Bottom` it will become valid.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialized the constructor `Top(int top)`, you put an int as a parameter, so you have to pass an int when you call the constructor. 
It works just like you are using a normal method.
The argument type must match the parameter type. You can't pass `void` argument to a method initialized with an `int`, or `double` parameter.