# Constructor not working after I am extending from another class

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I trying to run this code but I am getting stuck as to why the constructor is not working.

```
class Timber{

    String item_Name;
    int length;
    int width;
    String sku;
    
    public Timber(String name, int L, int W, String iSku){
        item_Name = name;
        length = L;
        width = W;
        sku = iSku;
    }
    
}


class Main extends Timber{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Timber small = new Timber("2 by 4", 2, 4, "1010");

        System.out.println(small.length);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Do you get a compile-time error, a run-time error, or unexpected output?

Comment: Your use of inheritance does not make any sense.

Comment: possible a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644317/java-constructor-inheritance ?

Comment: If you have a class that extends your `Timber` class then in the constructor of your child class you should explicitly add a call to the constructor of the `Timber` class by using a key-word **super** as a **first line**.

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I have figured it out. I am still learning so the help is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a default constructor in your Timber class.

```
public Timber() {}
```